# Routing and Remote Access in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, routing, hyper-v, cisco-anyconnect

My Windows 10 laptop is connected to corporate network by Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility and I'm looking for a way to provide Hyper-V VMs deployed on the laptop with that connection.

It looks impossible to create an external virtual switch over the Cisco AnyConnect adapter. Every time I tried to create one the connection got lost and the adapter was removed. Connection sharing is blocked by domain policies so that's not an option in my case.

The solution I'm considering is to set the Hyper-V host as a gateway for the VMs. For that purpose I've enabled Routing and Remote Access service (RRAS), connected the VMs by an external virtual switch directly to my home network and set the Hyper-V host as a default gateway in the guest OS (it's Linux if it's important). With that configuration VPN is unreachable as well as the Internet from the VMs. I tried to connect to my laptop with Remote Server Administration Tools to configure RRAS. It required to login but rejected my domain credentials.

Is it possible to configure Routing and Remote Access on Windows 10 to set it as a router for hosted Hyper-V VMs?

Comment: You should define the Hyper-V switch as using your physical adapter, then start Cisco for the host. This should also work for the default switch.

Comment: Using external switch based on a physical adapter provides connection to the Internet only, no to VPN. On the other hand, default switch gives access to both of them through NAT. It makes VMs inaccessible from outside, though. Anyway, @harrymc you gave me a clue. Thanks.